# Is there any way to analyze the outcome of each step of the optaplanner?

Tags: solver, optaplanner

I'm trying to solve a SKU (Stock Keeping Unit) sequencing problem on the production line in the company I work for.

In this problem, I have in average 2000 sku's to be sequenced in a single equipment. This equipment is released for production for 600 minutes per day. The time the sku will use will vary (production time + equipment setup time).

I am having difficulty analyzing the setup time of the equipment, since I need to check the original sku and what will be the next sku that will be producing.

Is there any way to analyze the step solver? Or is there any other way to analyze my equipment setup time?

We already tried to use Shadow Variable, but the performance was very low. Making the solution unfeasible.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on DEBUG logging, you'll see every step. If you turn on TRACE logging, you'll see every move evaluation too.

Generally, all this is too verbose, and the optaplanner-benchmark tool is a much better approach, as it has several statistics (most of which need to be turned on explicitly) to give insight as to what's going on.